# Using a singular widget for multiple functions that depend on the same parameter

Tags: python, slider, ipywidgets

I want to use a single slider widget for multiple functions that depend on the parameter, how can I go about doing it. This is what I have so far, but it's quite tacky:

```
def Func(c):
    Code
    return x,y,z

def Func_1(d):
    Code
    return x

interact(Func, c=widgets.FloatSlider(min,max...))
interact(Func_1, d=widgets.FloatSlider(min,max...))
```

I don't want to do this because this creates two separate slider I have to manually adjust to the same value, it's nonoptimal.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `ipywidgets`, but I presume there is a way to get the value in the callback function. So can you create a callback function that reads the value and calls another function based on that value?

Comment: [micro-optimization] is for questions about improving performance (execution speed), usually in ways that involve keeping the algorithm basically the same but tuning for a specific CPU or family of CPUs, or making a loop avoid some redundant work or similar.  It sounds like here you're talking about something that results in extra work for the human *user*, not for their CPU.  That's not a micro-optimization, that's implementing a UI design!  It's arguably not even an [optimization] question.

Comment: So I'm untagging [micro-optimization]; let me know if I misunderstood and this is just about saving a few CPU cycles in making the CPU update 1 thing instead of 2.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the edit, I didn't know that tag was irrelevant.

Comment: @David That might be a good Idea actually, I will try and update the question if it works.

Comment: @David Your suggestion worked, thank you! if you want you can type your comment as an answer, and I will accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function called for example `onslide`, which is the callback passed into `interact`. Then, inside that callback function, you can call the other functions that deal with the value.

Example:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interact

def onslide(s):
    if s < 5:
        Func(s)
    else:
        Func_1(s)
    
interact(onslide, s=(0.0, 10.0, 0.5))
```

Then inside `Func` and `Func_1` you can do value-dependent things.